# Force User to Capture Image in Landscape mode

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, user-experience

I would like my app to force a user to turn their phone sideways to take an image. In other words, I would like the image to be taken in landscape mode. How do I go about this?

At the very least, the image will be taken and saved in landscape even if user does not tilt their phone to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add this line in your `onCreate()` method inside your activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or if you need portrait write this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: Would this be a best practice? Or would it not matter?

Comment: I think don't matter, but I think that is more comfortable this because can active or desactive that line when you want, simply adding an if

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code in your Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.YourImageActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Comment: Would this be a best practice? Or would it not matter?